# How to add home icon in page title bar in ionic side menu template

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and I am developing an hybrid android app using ionic-cordova.

I am using ionic's side menu template and looking for a way to add home icon in page title bar in ionic side menu template. This icon will come in all the pages except home page.

Please share if you have the solution or any link where I can get any solution.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NiravRanpara thanks for your advice, but isn't it possible with "side menu template"?

Comment: I think you used menu in all other file. Check it again!

Answer (score 1):

Put that code in menu.html

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
            </button>
          <button class="button button-icon ion-home ">
            </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close ng-click="login()">
          Login
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/Setting">
          Setting
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/playlists ">
         playlists </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

And use angular ng-hide on home controller for hide home button or icon on home screen.

Comment: thanks for your time, I was looking to override ionic's directives, but finally resolved using css.